# R: Transformation of data with log10 qqline warning message the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, warnings, transformation

I want to transform my data in R with a logarithm and want to plot it with a qqplot. I got the warning message, see below. What does this exactly mean for the plot?

```
log <-log10(life$p) 
qqplot(life$p,log, main = "Normal Q-Q Plot",plot.it = TRUE)
qqline(life$p,log, col="red")
```

The warning message was:

> In if (datax) { :
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several things wrong here.

Your call to `qqplot` is almost certainly not doing what you wanted. 
Notice that the documentation  `?qqplot` says:

> qqplot produces a QQ plot of two datasets.

Your code is:
`qqplot(life$p,log, main = "Normal Q-Q Plot",plot.it = TRUE)`
The "two datasets" that you are giving it are life$p and log, so
this will plot the quantiles of life$p against the quantiles 
of log = log10(life$p).  That makes no sense. Since your title 
says "Normal Q-Q Plot", I suspect that you wanted to plot log 
against a Normal distribution. To get that, you probably wanted:
`qqnorm(log, main = "Normal Q-Q Plot")`

Now to your error message.
The documentation for `qqline` gives the argument sequence as:

```
qqline(y, datax = FALSE, distribution = qnorm,
       probs = c(0.25, 0.75), qtype = 7, ...)
```

Your call to this function is:

```
qqline(life$p,log, col="red")
```

You don't name the arguments so they are interpreted in order. 
life$p is y and log is datax. datax is supposed to be a logical
value (TRUE/FALSE), but you are passing it an array of numbers, 
hence the error message. I believe that what you intended was:

```
qqline(log, col="red")
```

Finally, `log` is the name of the natural logarithm function.
It is a bad idea to name your variable `log` since it will be 
confusing if that refers to the function or the variable.